# POST javascript into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying INSERT JavaScript/CSS/code into a MYSQL database. Adcode is being passed from a textarea to the PHP code below, Upon INSERT is successful with the adname, but blank with adcode..

QUESTIONs/ISSUE:

1. Why is it inputting blank code into the database instead of the code
   being passed
2. What is the most efficient why of doing this?
3. How can I pass the Adname and Adcode and UPDATE at the same time.

My FIRST code:Version 1 (fixed issue/question 1 in version two of the code below)

```
// Insert ad into database
    $ad = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adcode']);
    $insert = "INSERT INTO ads (adname, adcode) VALUES ('".$_POST['adname']."', '".$_POST['$ad']."')";
    $doit = mysql_query($insert);
```

My current code :Version 2 (for questions one and two)

```
if ($_GET['action'] == "editad") {  // Edit AD
    $newadcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adcode' . $ID]);
    $doedit = "UPDATE `adgate`.`ads` SET `ads`.`adcode` = '$newadcode' WHERE `ads`.`ID` = '$ID' LIMIT 1" or die(mysql_error());
    $retval = mysql_query( $doedit, $connection );
    if(! $retval )
    {
        die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
    //header("Location: displayads.php");
```

Comment: Careful; that’s rather vulnerable to SQL injection. You should escape `$_POST['adname']` and `$_POST['$ad']`, too, before putting them into the query. Even better, you could use prepared statements and PDO-MySQL or MySQLi 

Comment: how can i escape out of it. sorry I am just learning php. thanks for all the help!

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$adname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adname']);
$adcode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adcode']);
$insert = "INSERT INTO ads (adname, adcode) VALUES ('".$adname."', '".$adcode."')";
$doit = mysql_query($insert);
```

Comment: @Caiapfas No worries, welcome to Stackoverflow, and good luck with PHP!

Answer (score 1):

Spot the mistake:

```
$ad = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adcode']);
^^^
... "... VALUES ('".$_POST['adname']."', '".$_POST['$ad']."')";
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Enable error reporting during development! This would have thrown a nice warning.

Comment: thanks good info. turned it on and found the issue and then some...LOL